# Remove text that is not inside a tag in html

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html like this :

```
text = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
. remove me 
</body>
</html>"""
```

What i want to do is to remove anything that is not inside a tag `(. remove me)` in this case

my code so far :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
. remove me
</body>
</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
print("".join(soup.strings))
```

But it doesn't remove it

***Expected Output*** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
. remove me 
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

for txt in soup.body.find_all(text=True, recursive=False):
    if not txt.strip():
        continue
    txt.replace_with("\n") # or txt.extract() to completely remove it

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please explain the loop, why it's having recursive??

Comment: @user16085212 The loop iterates over all `NavigableString`s under `<body>` tag and replaces them with `\n` (if they aren't empty)

Comment: excuse me but in some html files i don't have the body tag, is there a way to get the job done without having the body tag??

Comment: @You can ommit then the `.body` part

Comment: @user16085212 You need then to specify the tag where you want to remove the strings. Try `.html` instead of `.body`, but without knowing structure of your HTML document I cannot give you an 100% answer.

Comment: here is an example of my html structure : https://pastebin.com/jJLrAWcg, if you go to line 42 u gonna find a dot at the end

Comment: @user16085212 Yes, but this dot (`.`) is inside tag `<p>`. To not clutter the comment section, I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.